# How to open save dialog box instead of file getting opened in browser for my Sharepoint site

Tags: javascript, html, sharepoint

My site is developed in SharePoint 2010. 
In my Testing site, 
`<a href="file.pdf" target="_blank">Download File</a>`

when click on the above a tag, file opens directly in browswer(IE/Chrome/FireFox)

But same a tag is used in my Live site where it ask to save file(In IE) or gets downloaded(in Chrome).

Comment: Have you checked this http://www.mydigitallife.info/disable-pdf-from-opening-in-web-browser-ie-firefox-opera-safari/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For link on file use standard SharePoint download.aspx page.

```
<a href="http://yourSite/_layouts/download.aspx?SourceUrl=http://pathToFile" target="_blank">Download File</a>
```

Download.aspx will read the content of the file you send as the SourceUrl, and render it back to you on the HTTP response.

Hope that helps

Comment: Dont forget to add filters to the downliad.aspx or anyone can get othe files! ;)